# Mobile browser VoiceXML support

Tags: browser, mobile, mobile-website, voice, voicexml

I'm wondering is there a support from mobile browsers of VoiceXML. If so, which one support it.

Thanks,

Comment: Mobiles don't usually process the VoiceXML- how are you planning to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoiceXML (at least version 2.0 and 2.1) was not designed to be consumed by client-side browsers. The main objective of the spec was to enable server-side VoiceXML browsers to answer calls and, in response, to execute the relevant VoiceXML documents thus generating a conversation on the line.

Theoretically, one could build a mobile browser that executes VoiceXML on the client-side. The closest version to that was the custom browser built by IBM + Opera in their [X+V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML+Voice) venture. It [seems](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/voice/) that the Opera desktop browser has retained some of that functionality. Since then I have not seen any client-side implementations, let alone mobile ones.